# How to use RSA to encrypt a JWT token?

Tags: c#, .net-core, f#, jwt, jwe

I have a OpenSSL key pair that I use to create the RSA object:

```
  let getSigningKey (rsa:RSA) (key) =
    try
      rsa.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(
        source = ReadOnlySpan(trimOpenSslPrivKey key),
        bytesRead = ref 0
      )
      Some rsa
    with ex ->
      LambdaLogger.Log <| sprintf "Exception : %s" ex.Message
      None
```

Once it is created I can use it to sign the JWT tokens no problem.

However, once I would like to create encrypted JWT (JWE) I am not sure how this can be used.

Signing:

```
  let getSigningCredentials () =
    try
      getRsa()
      |> Option.map (fun rsa ->
        let signingCredentials =
          SigningCredentials(RsaSecurityKey(rsa), SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256)
        signingCredentials.CryptoProviderFactory <- CryptoProviderFactory(CacheSignatureProviders = false)
        signingCredentials)
    with ex ->
      LambdaLogger.Log(sprintf "Exception : %s" ex.Message)
      None
```

And finally the JWT creation:

```
   JwtSecurityToken(
      issuer = "Bob",
      signingCredentials = signingCredentials,
      claims = claims,
      notBefore = Nullable notBefore,
      expires = Nullable expires
    )
```

I think it should be similar:

```
  SecurityTokenDescriptor(
      Issuer = "Bob",
      Claims = claims,
      NotBefore = Nullable notBefore,
      Expires = Nullable expires,
      EncryptingCredentials = ??,
      SigningCredentials = signingCredentials
    )
```

I am not sure how to use RSA as the EncryptingCredentials.